# How to dynamically create elements in VTK?

Tags: c++, 3d, vtk, primitive

I've been trying to create primitives from a text input file in VTK. It means, That my input file could be for example:

```
cube s x y z
sphere r x y z
cube s x y z
cone r h x y z
```

Where I have the name of the element and some attributes such as Position, radius, etc, depending on the primitive. All I have done so far is to put 1 actor for each primitive in the same rendered scene. So my program would draw a cube, a sphere and a cone based on the example above. However what I want to accomplish is to dynamically draw whatever the input says.

I supposse I have to create an actor for every object in the scene. However I don't know how many objects the input indicates before running it. I was thinking about a list of actors (because I can push as many actors to the list as the input says), but I'm not sure if it's neccessary.

Need big help over here. ty

Answer (score 0):

What you need a [vtkActorCollection](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkActorCollection.html#details). Think of it as a list of actors. You will supply the number of actors (the number of your premitives), and iterate through the collection and connect a suitable source to it.

Comment: Is it better to use a vtkActorCollection or to use a vector of actors, declared this way vector<vtkActor>

Comment: Probably identical, but I am not sure.